# php-encrypt comparing two data

Tags: php, encryption

i'm still a newbie and a new coder in encrypting the data in php, i have a data encrypted with iv in the database now the problem is that when the user try to search that data i will compare the data he inputted to the database data in sql kind like of `WHERE tbl_column = "user_input"`. is there any better way to compare two data (plain data check to encrypted data) here is my code.

```
<?php
$input = 'sample';

$key = "secretkey";
$secretMethod = 'AES-256-CBC';
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);

echo $database_data = openssl_encrypt('sample', $secretMethod, $key, 0, $iv);

echo $data = $iv.$emessage;

$iv = substr($data, 0, $iv_size);

echo '<br/>Decrypted: '.openssl_decrypt(substr($data, $iv_size), $umethod, $key, 0, $iv);

if($data == $input) {
    echo 'equal';
} else {
    echo 'not-equal';
}

?>
```

Comment: A major advantage of encrypting with an IV is to make it hard to blanket search for something.

Comment: you will have to encrypt the user data and compare it to the data in the database, or decrypt data from database and compare it to the plain data provided by the user.

Comment: @xanadev i already did that encrypting the users input too, but it gives me false and already figured it out because of the iv generating randomly everytime i encrypt new data.

Comment: @apokryfos yeah, that is why it is hard for me to compare two datas in sql.

Comment: My point is you can't have both in this case. You made the choice of security over easily finding data. You need to sit down and think about what is more important in your use case.

Comment: @apokryfos i have an idea that i will retrieve first all the data in database and store it decrypted in the array and thats the time i will compare it.

Answer (score 0):

i am working with this solution for encryption/decryption
1- encryption:

```
function crypt_val($val){
      $token = $val;
      $enc_method = 'AES-128-CTR';
      $enc_key = openssl_digest(gethostname() . "|" . $key, 'SHA256', true);
      $enc_iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length($enc_method));
      $crypted_token = openssl_encrypt($token, $enc_method, $enc_key, 0, $enc_iv) . "::" . bin2hex($enc_iv);
      return $crypted_token;
    }
```

2- decryption:

```
function decrypt_val($val){
      $crypted_token = $val;
      if(preg_match("/^(.*)::(.*)$/", $crypted_token, $regs)) {
      list(, $crypted_token, $enc_iv) = $regs;
      $enc_method = 'AES-128-CTR';
      $enc_key = openssl_digest(gethostname() . "|" . $key, 'SHA256', true);
      $decrypted_token = openssl_decrypt($crypted_token, $enc_method, $enc_key, 0, hex2bin($enc_iv));
      return $decrypted_token;
    }
  }
```

The first function will crypt an entered string, an the second will decrypt it 
Note that **$key** is your secret key, it will be used for encryption/decryption process